# Cannot delete a web application

Tags: 2013, error, web-application, delete

I am trying to delete a web application in my SharePoint 2013 environment. The first attempt deleted the database, the application pool, the IIS site... But the I got an error saying

> An object of the type
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebsiteUnprovisioningJobDefinition
>   named "Unprovisioning Webapplication" already exists under the parent
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService named "".  Rename
>   your object or delete the existing object.

So I deleted the corresponding jobs, as I have seen in other blogs and questions, and then tried to delete the web application once again. This time I get this error:

> An object in the SharePoint administrative framework,
>   "SPWebApplication Name=Webapplication", could not be deleted because
>   other objects depend on it.  Update all of these dependants to point
>   to null or different objects and retry this operation.  The dependant
>   objects are as follows:

However, there are no dependencies being displayed in the message. The logs don't provide any information either.

UPDATE: This web application had 3 site collections on it:

/

/Sites/A

/Sites/B

Where the first and second site collections had 1 shared database, and the last one had a separate database. All site collections and all databases are deleted though.

Comment: Try to delete it using powershell.

Comment: How many web applications are there, in your central administration.

Comment: Powershell does not make it either. Same error. There are 8 web applications (including the one I need to delete)

Comment: I have also tried to create a new database, attach it to the web application and try again. Still no success

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have some kind of solution deployed to this web app.
you should check this

- Go to `Central Administration>Operations>Solution Management` .Here you
  can check whether there are any solutions deployed on the web
  application. if there is any, please remove it from the web app.
- from central admin check if there is any timer job running for the web app.
- Restart the SharePoint timer services and sharepoint admin services on all servers.
- Now try to remove it with powershell using -force switch.

Comment: It is a brand new web applications, no solutions deployed. Still, I will try it.